# LINQ IQueryable GroupBy giving wrong results

Tags: c#, sql, linq, group-by, iqueryable

first some code (simplified for the question's purpose):

Entity:

```
[View( "SupplierSearchViewView", 1 )]
public class SupplierSearchViewView : IViewDefinition
{
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DocumentTypeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MainContactId { get; set; }
    public int SourceLanguageId { get; set; }
    public int TargetLanguageId { get; set; }
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SectorId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DisciplineId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SkillLevelId { get; set; }
}
```

A Linq Query:

```
    public IQueryable<SupplierSearchViewView> GetQuery( SupplierSearchCriteria sc, int? supplierId = null )
    {
        return this.supplierSearchViewViewRepository.GetManyNoTracking(
            x => new int[] { 84 }.Contains( x.SourceLanguageId )
                &&
                new int[] { 2 }.Contains( x.TargetLanguageId )
                &&
                new int[] { 35, 36 }.Contains( x.TaskId )
                &&
                x.SkillLevelId.HasValue && new int[] { 2, 3 }.Contains( x.SkillLevelId.Value )
                );
    }
```

(of course original method uses sc object - but this one is simplified to hardcoded values for test/presentation purposes)

this query returns 495 total count with 14 unique suppliers (which is correct)

and now the Group By thing...

```
        var query = GetQuery( sc );

        var groupedQuery = query.GroupBy( x => x.SupplierId );

        var tmp = groupedQuery.OrderBy( x => x.Key ).Skip( skip ).Take( take ).ToList();
```

when query done like that result is:
14 groups (which is correct of course, and all have correct IDs too)
but... the groups are filled with much less items they should (edit: basically each group has some missing elements)

but... if i do a little trick in this line:

```
        var groupedQuery = query.ToList().GroupBy( x => x.SupplierId );
```

the result is... correct.

also in database when i use an sql like that:

```
    select x.SupplierId, count(*) from
    (
        select distinct *
        from SupplierSearchViewView ssvv
        where ssvv.TaskId in (35,36)
        and ssvv.SourceLanguageId = 84
        and ssvv.SkillLevelId in (2,3)
        and ssvv.TargetLanguageId = 2
    ) x 
    group by x.SupplierId
```

i get results like in 2nd case (the one with "early ToList()" )

i will really appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Sorry maybe I'm just missing it... but what issue are you having?

Comment: @Kritner
when query done like that result is: 14 groups (which is correct of course, and all have correct IDs too) but... the groups are filled with much less items they should (edit: basically each group has some missing elements)

this is the issue ;) 
when GroupBy is done on IQueryable object (code without ToList) the total count of results is much less than it should (495 is correct number while like 70 is returned)

PS sorry accidentally pressed enter on before commend and didn't manage to edit it in 5 mins

Comment: Can you log what SQL is being produced?